# Bottle for Python : How to use the bottle as an attribute

Tags: python, api, bottle

I want to design an API using Bottle for Python 3.6, but I don't see how to bind route to function with a bottle attribute as `@self.bottle.route...` decorators are not allowed.
What I have is :

```py
from bottle import Bottle, request
class API_v1:
    def __init__(self, repository):
        self.bottle = Bottle()
        self.repository = repository

        @self.bottle.error(400)
        def error400(error):
            return error.body

        @self.bottle.error(500)
        def error500(error):
            return f'Technical exception : {error.body}'

        @self.bottle.put('/job')
        def job():
            #do stuff with repository
            return ''
```

(notice all functions are initialized inside `__init__`, it's quite bad)

What I want is something like :

```py
from bottle import Bottle, request
class API_v1:
    def __init__(self, repository):
        self.bottle = Bottle()
        self.repository = repository

    @self.bottle.error(400)
    def error400(self, error):
        return error.body

    @self.bottle.error(500)
    def error500(self, error):
        return f'Technical exception : {error.body}'

    @self.bottle.put('/job')
    def job(self):
        #do stuff with repository
        return ''
```

What is the best pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason all these methods are in a class?

Comment: I want to inject my repository at runtime and to be able to manage instance attributes